# Could not install package NLog 4.3.0-alpha3 in Xamarin iOS Project

Tags: ios, xamarin, nlog

I am trying to add the NLog package in my Xamarin Solution using Xamarin Studio. There is not a problem adding the library to a Xamarin Android Project. But it seems that NLog can not be added to my Xamarin iOS Project.

Package Console:

> Adding NLog... Adding 'NLog 4.3.0-alpha3' to TestApp.iOS. Could not
>   install package 'NLog 4.3.0-alpha3'. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but
>   the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
>   that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact
>   the package author.

According to the nuget package [description](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.3.0-alpha3), it supports Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: To me, it looks like the `.nuget` is not configured correctly.. It is targeting `MonoTouch10` thus the classic iOS, where it should be `Xamarin.iOS10`. The `lib/MonoTouch10/NLog.dll` inside the `.nuget` does properly ref `Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0` so you can zip the `.nuget` and add a manual reference to it in project to unblock yourself.... Also fill a github issue.

Comment: I made already a github issue.        https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1152

Comment: This should be fixed in NLog 4.3.0-alpha4

Comment: Thanks it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed, this is fixed in NLog 4.3.0-alpha4.

Please note that Xamarin Support is still in Alpha state.